# Calling Stored Procedure in Python - ORA-04063: error

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have a python script which calls a stored procedure. I'm pretty sure my python script is OK as when it calls the stored proc I get this error:

```
ORA-04063: package body "db.package_name" has errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "db.package_name" ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I have also sometimes gotten this error:

```
ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at "db.package_name", line 16 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Viewing the package in SQL dev I see a red x over its name and right-click > compile gives this:

```
Error(10): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     begin end function pragma procedure
```

The procdure it calls also has a red x and compiling that gives:

```
Error(5,3): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

So this is leading me to believe that it is a prob with package/procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the problem is with the procedure, not with Python.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can send back to person who gave me stored procedure rather than blame my python script :)